# How can I get a list of all user alerts set on a site collection in SPO?

Tags: client-object-model, web-services, sharepoint-online, alert

I need to retrieve a list of user alerts set on a particular site collection in SharePoint Online.  This is possible through the web UI under Site Settings -> User Alerts, but requires that I choose one user at a time, rather than supplying a list of all alerts for all users.

I'm perfectly happy with programmatic solutions, but as this is SPO I can't use anything server side (only Client Object Model or Web Services, as I understand it).  I have spent a ridiculous amount of time Googling this and come up short.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: The "getAlerts" function in "Alert Web Service" gives the alerts only for the current user...
Is there a way to get the others users alerts ? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the alerts web service, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/alerts.alerts.getalerts.aspx, to get that information. There is a simple wrapper for the web services if you want to use jQuery, [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Alerts&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices).

Comment: This is super old but I'm sure many people stumble across this, particularly when migrating from server-side solutions dealing with SPAlerts into solutions using Client APIs. There is *no* client object model, REST, JSOM or legacy wss 3.0 SOAP method to retrieve alerts for any user other than the currently logged in one. 

We had a solution which generated a report of users who had alerts on a site which was deployed as full-trust code. It is impossible to redevelop that solution as a client-side only solution.